# pgbouncer port vs db port

Tags: postgresql, pgbouncer

I used PostgreSQL with php. After a while the client connection become larger so I try to use pgbouncer to set the max connection etc. My DB port is 5432 and all my php using that port to connect to my DB. My question is, what if I used the same port 5432 and set to pgbouncer listen port? So my DB and pgbouncer used the same port so I don't have to change the client code. Thanks

Comment: If pgbouncer runs on a different computer that should not be a problem.

Comment: If pgbouncer isn't on a different computer, then you obviously can't use the same port. You could change PG's port though, then use 5432 for pgbouncer.

Answer (score 2):

you can't run two different application on the same port but you can use 5432 on pgbouncer and use a different port for your database (eg 6432).

to change the port on postgresql edit your *postgresql.conf*:

```
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# CONNECTIONS AND AUTHENTICATION
#------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# - Connection Settings -
(...)
port = 6432                             # (change requires restart)
```